# SwiftUI master/detail view with modifications

Tags: swiftui

### Goal

My goal is to build a master/detail view for a macOS application:

[image]

### Problem

I managed to implement code that works, but found myself needing to use an awkward `Binding` syntax to do so:

```
Binding<String>(get: { selectedItem.text }, set: { model.selectedItem?.text = $0 })
```

### Code

I began with my `Item` model:

```
struct Item: Codable, Identifiable, Equatable, Hashable {
  let id: String
  var title: String
  var text: String 
}
```

Both the `title` and `text` are mutable because I want to allow the detail view to modify these properties. Next, I defined my view model:

```
@Observable @MainActor class HomeViewModel {
  private(set) var items: [Item] = [...]
  var selectedItem: Item?
}
```

The `items` array will be used to populate a list in my master view. Selecting an item in the list will assign the item to `selectedItem`.

I created the master and detail views here:

```
struct MasterView: View {
  @Binding var selectedItem: Item?
  let items: [Item]
 
  var body: some View {
    List(items) { item in
      Text(item.title)
    }
    .onTapGesture { selectedItem = item }
  }
}
```

```
struct DetailView: View {
  @Binding var title: String
  @Binding var text: String
 
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      TextField("Title", text: $title)
      TextField("Text", text: $text)
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, I glued everything together with the `HomeView`:

```
struct HomeView: View {
  @State var model: HomeViewModel
 
  var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
      NavigationSplitView {
        MasterView(selectedItem: $model.selectedItem, items: model.items)
      } detail: {
        if let selectedItem = model.selectedItem {
          DetailView(
            title: .init(get: { selectedItem.title }, set: { model.selectedItem?.title = $0 }),
            text: .init(get: { selectedItem.text }, set: { model.selectedItem?.text = $0 })
          )
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Question

Is there a more idiomatic way to implement this?

Comment: remove the class, View struct is the view model already, selected item should be a state

Comment: Binding is for value types Bindable and State are for Observable. State is a source of truth and should always be marked private

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion:

First set the type of `selectedItem` to the `ID` of the model, this is necessary to let the `List` manage the selection. Further declare `items` as `internal` and add a property to get the index of the selected item

```
@MainActor
@Observable class HomeViewModel {
    
    var items: [Item] = [Item(title: "Alpha", text: "a"), Item(title: "Beta", text: "b"), Item(title: "Gamma", text: "c")]
    var selectedItem: Item.ID?
    
    var selectedIndex : Int? {
        items.firstIndex{$0.id == selectedItem}
    }
}
```

In the `@main` struct create the view model and put it into the environment. The `init` method is necessary to get rid of the actor error

```
@main
struct TestMacApp: App {
    @State private var viewModel : HomeViewModel
   
    init() {
        let model = HomeViewModel()
        self._viewModel = State(wrappedValue: model)
    }

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            HomeView()
                .frame(width: 350)
                .environment(viewModel)
        }
    }
}
```

In `HomeView` show the DetailView only if something is selected. To avoid the Optional Binding pass the unwrapped selected index to `DetailView`

```
struct HomeView: View {
    @Environment(HomeViewModel.self) var model: HomeViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            NavigationSplitView {
                MasterView()
            } detail: {
                if let selectedIndex = model.selectedIndex {
                    DetailView(index: selectedIndex)
                } else {
                    Text("Nothing selected")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In `MasterView` take advantage of the `selection` parameter of `List`

```
struct MasterView: View {
    @Environment(HomeViewModel.self) var model: HomeViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        @Bindable var model = model
        List(model.items, selection: $model.selectedItem) { item in
            Text(item.title)
        }
    }
}
```

In `DetailView` bind the `text` properties to the item at selected index

```
struct DetailView: View {
    @Environment(HomeViewModel.self) var model: HomeViewModel
    let index : Int
    
    var body: some View {
        @Bindable var model = model
        VStack {
            TextField("Title", text: $model.items[index].title)
            TextField("Text", text: $model.items[index].text)
        }
    }
}
```